# Reindex from duplicate axis error while using glob.glob

Tags: python, pandas, glob

When I try to run this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
files = [pd.read_excel(p, skipfooter=1) for p in glob.glob("path/*.xlsx")]
df = files[0].append([files[i] for i in range(1,len(files))])       
df.loc[(df[df.columns[6]] == 2002040041),'New Column'] = df[df.columns[2]]
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in
>
> ---> 5 df.loc[(df[df.columns[6]] == 2002040041),'New Column'] = df[df.columns[2]]
>
> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

However, when I write a .csv, and then read it, the problem is solved.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
files = [pd.read_excel(p, skipfooter=1) for p in glob.glob("path/*.xlsx")]
df = files[0].append([files[i] for i in range(1,len(files))])
df.to_csv("file.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig')
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv") 
df.loc[(df[df.columns[6]] == 2002040041),'New Column'] = df[df.columns[2]]
```

If I use `df.to_excel` instead, the error persists.

Why is this error happening? How can I solve it without writing a .csv file? All column names are the same in every file and different from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need default index by `reset_index(drop=True)`:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or by parameter `ignore_index=True` in [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
df = files[0].append([files[i] for i in range(1,len(files))], ignore_index=True)
```

Then code should be simplify:

```
df.loc[df.iloc[:, 6] == 2002040041, 'New Column'] = df.iloc[:, 2]
```